# zone.js:25 Uncaught Error: Zone already loaded

Tags: angular, zone

my angular application loads on click of a button. When the button is clicked secound time, it give me `Zone already loaded` error because zone.js content is loaded when angular2 is loaded first time.

How I will check the zone is already loaded and then can preventing to try to load it if its available?

When I delete (answered below) zone by `delete window['zone']` and try to reload it again its showing `zone.js:984 Uncaught ReferenceError: Zone is not defined`

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates your problem

Comment: I am using angular-cli to build my project. once it build it create only 2 files including zone.js and I load my angular app on click of a button, when the button clicked 2nd time it shows the error.

Comment: The point is i can edit the created file by angular-cli and check if zone is loaded or not but how can i do that automatically from angular-cli or through other way.

Comment: @yurzui, code: var

 Zone$1 = (function (global) {
    if (global.Zone) {
        throw new Error('Zone already loaded.');
    }

It comes from the angular-cli build generated code

Comment: This error occurs when you're trying to include zone.js script second time.

Comment: Maybe you're including another script which has zonejs as a dependency

Comment: @yurzui yes I know. Actually as I mentioned I cannot avoid or stop user to download my lib twice as my angular app is coming under another app on click of a button.

Comment: Try to call `delete global['Zone'];` before repeated loading zonejs

Comment: When I try delete global['zone']; I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined. I am building my angular roject using angular-cli

Comment: `delete window.Zone` or `delete window['Zone']`

Comment: @yurzui, delete window.Zone able to delete it but when another angular2 module loads it says zone is not defined. I there a way to handle this zone problem in angular2

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this ...

```js
$(function (){
  function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
     var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
     var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
     var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
     for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
     if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
         allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
     }
  }
 var jsCustomerTag = $("head").children("#jsShimTag");
    if (jsCustomerTag.length == 0) {
     jsCustomerTag = document.createElement('script');
     jsCustomerTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
     jsCustomerTag.setAttribute("src", " <your js file> ");
     jsCustomerTag.id = "jsShimTag";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsCustomerTag);
    }

   jsCustomerTag = null;
});
```

Comment: this is one way of removing scripts from the browser and reload it again. let me try it